# How to initialize server-side Meteor Collection without needing to interact with it?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, meteor

I'm new to [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/), and building a simple recipe list.

I have a file (`/imports/api/recipes.ts`) which defines my Recipe collection:

```
// imports/api/recipes.ts
export interface Recipe {
  _id?: string;
  title: string;
  createdAt: Date;
}

export const RecipesCollection = new Mongo.Collection<Recipe>("recipes");
```

And I can import/interact with that collection on the client side (in a React component) fairly easily.

**However:** Changes don't stick! Inserts flash briefly, but are then reverted in the browser when the "Optimistic UI" realizes the operation failed:

[image]

The only way I've been able to make this example work, is to interact with the imported collection in `server/main.ts`. (Not just include via a named import.)

Every example I've found explains this away by installing some "initial seed data" as a convenience - but I'm having trouble graduating this approach to something more realistic.

If I import the collection in `/server/main.ts` but don't touch it:

```
// server/main.ts
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor";
import { RecipesCollection } from "/imports/api/recipes";

Meteor.startup(async () => {});
```

The insert fails with the error in the screenshot above. However, if I do something semi-meaningless like this:

```
// server/main.ts
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor";
import { RecipesCollection } from "/imports/api/recipes";

Meteor.startup(async () => {
  console.log(`On startup, saw ${RecipesCollection.find().count()} recipes`);
});
```

Then the application functions as expected. Is there a more straightforward way to signal to Meteor that I'd like this collection to be "plumbed" for server-side persistence and interaction with Mongo?

Comment: Can you please add to the code examples which of them is on server and which is on the client? Since Meteor collections are isomorphic by design this is not always clear without further explanation.

Comment: @Jankapunkt I added comments to the top of each snippet to make it a bit more clear which file it came from.

Comment: Could you show where you are subscribing? Also, if you no longer have the `autopublish` package enabled, please show your publications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will always need to import collection code somewhere on the server, but not necessarily interact with it.  In anything larger than just a demo this will probably happen naturally because you'll end up importing your collections so that you can write allow/deny logic, attach hooks, or use them within your Meteor methods.

In the case of your above code a simple one line import with just the file path should work.

```js
import "/imports/api/recipies";
```

Edit:
It turns out the specific reason this is happening is because the typescript compiler removes imports where all references are unused.

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4717

Comment: Excuse my naivety, but what's the difference in terms of execution/plumbing when importing like: `import { RecipesCollection } from "/imports/api/recipes";` versus `import "/imports/api/recipies";`, other than the latter works, and the former doesn't?

Comment: Honestly apart from destructuring the exports of the imported file these should be functionally the same. It's surprising to me that the former doesn't work and I'm actually planning to explore this myself to see if I can reproduce it.

Comment: Yea, it's reproducible on my end, for a pretty barebones project.

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect this difference is actually the result of the TypeScript compiler stripping away my named import (as obviously unused, unless I interact with it), and leaving the path-only import, in the resulting JS - but I'm not super familiar with Meteor's build dir, so haven't confirmed.

Comment: @CraigOtis Probably exactly what is happening and didn't even think of that.. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4717